# What Is STOPzilla virus?

Tags: virus

I was using my PC in darkness.Brightness of PC was too shiny.
I downloaded [**Flux**](https://justgetflux.com/) software.
I scanned it on [**metadefender**](https://www.metadefender.com/#!/results/file/ZTE2MTIwN0JrOEp4dUpIUWdIeTVYSmxUSTda/regular/analysis).
It says 1 threat detected(***STOPzilla***).
I searched on **Google** that what is it.I got nothing except **anti-STOPzilla**.
I visited the following page but it was not understand-able to me cause I am not too professional at english:
[**Is STOPzilla a safe program?**](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/313493/is-stopzilla-a-safe-program/)
Can Anybody help me that what virus is it?

Comment: Do you refer to this [metadefender](https://www.opswat.com/package-options-it-admins?utm_referrer=https%3A//www.opswat.com/products/metadefender/core/multi-scanning)? If so, could it be that it just wants to state that its Multi-Scanning engine got a (false-)positive from STOPzilla for your file (so basically a 1/30 rating)?

Comment: Since STOPZilla is an antivirus engine rather than malware, this is not a duplicate.  Voting to reopen.

Comment: You Can check the [result on metadefender](https://www.metadefender.com/#!/results/file/ZTE2MTIwN0JrOEp4dUpIUWdIeTVYSmxUSTda/regular/analysis)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

STOPZilla is a scanning engine. Its not a virus, its an Anti-Virus engine. Meta Defender uses this engine, and the message you received was that the STOPZilla engine found a virus.

See [here](https://onlinehelp.opswat.com/corev3/Do_any_of_the_custom_engines_have_updating_limitations_.html), a list of scanning engines used by Meta Defender.

Comment: In any case, f.lux (the link in the question is to the f.lux site) is perfectly safe to use and the scan was more than likely a false positive.

Comment: Wait a minute.If **STOPzilla** is a search engine, then It scanned the virus?@LPChip

Comment: It shows The following: **Hijacker.Win32.Feedcath**

Comment: At a rate of 1/30 (or 1/40), one can almost safely assume that it's a false-positive. Usually, I'd suggest to check the hash of the file, but f.lux does not provide a hash as far as I can see. In this case, I'd use [virustotal](https://www.virustotal.com/) or any other analysation tool to check again. But in any case, as STOPzilla isn't one of the major players (or so it would seem), I believe that it's simply wrong about f.lux.

Comment: @flolilolilo ,Are you sure?

Comment: Should I install this software with closed eyes?

Comment: That's for you to decide. If they got compromised, I would expect them to write a blog-entry later that day that says "Hey people, our website got hacked and f.lux was replaced with an infected version. Now everything's back to normal." It seems **very unlikely** that their site got hacked and nobody noticed for such a long timespan, except from STOPzilla. But of course, that's just logic, which has nothing to do with the (ir)rational fear of malicious software. Rule of thumb: *If you don't trust it, don't install it.*

Comment: @ShopiMacros: Hijacker.Win32.Feedcath is the name of the virus that STOPZilla found, but as the rest points out, there is a big chance it's a false positive.

Comment: **Windows Defender** is saying that no threats detected.